# excel adding a few days to a date then auto populating a cell in another sheet with it

Tags: vba, excel, date

as said in the title I need a cell in another sheet to auto fill with the new date that has had a number of days added onto the current date, here is my code that I cant get to work:

```
Sub dateplus()

Dim destSheet As Worksheet: Set destSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Dim Ldate As Date

Ldate = dateadd("d", 2, "6/14/2016")

destSheet.range("A1").Value = Ldate

End Sub
```

I am not entirely familiar with this command of dateadd, what do I need to change in order for this code to do what I am trying to accomplish?

Thank you

Comment: you're naming your sub after "dateadd" which is the same name of the VBA function `DateAdd()`. Thus when you're typing `Ldate = dateadd("d", 2, "6/14/2016")` VBA thinks you're calling your own sub which however doesn't have any argument. Moreover if you want to refer to current date, you have to use VBA `Date()` function. Finally you're declaring `destSheet` but then set `Set sourceSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")`, so no object is available when you refer to `destSheet` in `destSheet.range("A1").Value = Ldate` statement. See my answer

Comment: you're welcome. if my answer fulfilled your question please mark it as accepted. thank you

Comment: it helped, but ar4i had what i was trying to do more exactly in his answer

Comment: well the question was _"I need a cell in another sheet to auto fill with the new date that has had a number of days added onto the current date,"_. what did I miss in my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Option Explicit

Sub MyDateAdd()
    Dim destSheet As Worksheet: Set destSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    destSheet.Range("A1").Value = dateadd("d", 2, Date)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your `destSheet` isn't initialized, instead `sourceSheet` is. And to use DateAdd you need a Date object, not a string. It should look like this:

```
Sub CustomDateAdd()

Dim destSheet As Worksheet
Dim Ldate As Date

Set destSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Ldate = DateAdd("d", 2, Now)

destSheet.range("A1").Value = Format(Ldate,"MM/dd/yyyy")

End Sub
```

Why not use the Excel formula instead of calculating manually?

```
Sub CustomDateAdd()

Dim destSheet As Worksheet
Set destSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

destSheet.range("A1").Formula = "=TODAY()+2"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Added some comments to your code, hope this will help

```
Sub dateadd() ' Same name as a defined function, this will be a cause of Problems

Dim destSheet As Worksheet: Set sourceSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'the variable sourceSheet is neither initialised nor used
Dim Ldate As Date

Ldate = dateadd("d", 2, "6/14/2016") 'the vba function you want to call is DateAdd, but here vba will call the sub dateadd because it has the same name. Will throw an Wrong Argument Count error.

destSheet.Range("A1").Value = Ldate

End Sub
```